# How to simplify python code in for loop or another

Tags: python, for-loop, elementtree

I have the following development which I'm working with the ElementTree and Pandas module in Python:

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import pandas as pd
    
    file_xml = ET.parse('example1.xml')
    rootXML = file_xml.getroot()
    
    def transfor_data_atri(rootXML):
        file_xml = ET.parse(rootXML)
        data_XML = [
            {"Name": signal.attrib["Name"],
             # "Value": signal.attrib["Value"]
             "Value": int(signal.attrib["Value"].split(' ')[0])
             } for signal in file_xml.findall(".//Signal")
        ]
        
        signals_df = pd.DataFrame(data_XML)
        extract_name_value(signals_df)
        
    def extract_name_value(signals_df):
        #print(signals_df)
        
        signal_ig_st = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin(["Status"])]
        row_values_ig_st = signal_ig_st.T
        vector_ig_st = row_values_ig_st.iloc[[1]]
        
        signal_nav_DSP_rq = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin(["SetDSP"])]
        row_values_nav_DSP_rq = signal_nav_DSP_rq.T
        vector_nav_DSP_rq = row_values_nav_DSP_rq.iloc[[1]]
        
        signal_HMI_st = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin(["HMI"])]
        row_values_HMI_st = signal_HMI_st.T
        vector_HMI_st = row_values_HMI_st.iloc[[1]]
        
        signal_delay_ac = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin(["Delay"])]
        row_values_delay_ac = signal_delay_ac.T
        vector_delay_ac = row_values_delay_ac.iloc[[1]]
        
        signal_AutoConfigO_Rear = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin(["AutoConfigO_Rear"])]
        row_values_AutoConfigO_Rear = signal_AutoConfigO_Rear.T
        vector_AutoConfigO_Rear = row_values_AutoConfigO_Rear.iloc[[1]]
        
        signal_ACO_Front = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin(["AutoConfigO_Front"])]
        row_values_ACO_Front = signal_ACO_Front.T
        vertor_ACO_Front = row_values_ACO_Front.iloc[[1]]
        
        signal_ACO_Drvr = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin(["AutoConfigO_Drvr"])]
        row_values_ACO_Drvr = signal_ACO_Drvr.T
        vector_ACO_Drvr = row_values_ACO_Drvr.iloc[[1]]
        
        signal_ACO_Allst = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin(["AutoConfigO_Allst"])]
        row_values_ACO_Allst = signal_ACO_Allst.T
        vector_ACO_Allst = row_values_ACO_Allst.iloc[[1]]
        
        signal_RURRq_st = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin(["RUResReqstStat"])]
        row_values_RURRq_st = signal_RURRq_st.T
        vector_RURRq_st = row_values_RURRq_st.iloc[[1]]
        
        signal_RURqSy_st = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin(["RUReqstrSystem"])]
        row_values_RURqSy_st = signal_RURqSy_st.T
        vector_RURqSy_st = row_values_RURqSy_st.iloc[[1]]
        
        signal_RUAudS_st = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin(["RUSource"])]
        row_values_RUAudS_st = signal_RUAudS_st.T
        vector_RUAudS_st = row_values_RUAudS_st.iloc[[1]]
        
        signal_DSP_st = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin(["DSP"])]
        row_values_DSP = signal_DSP.T
        vector_DSP = row_values_DSP.iloc[[1]]
        
        print('1: ', vector_ig_st)
        print('2: ', vector_nav_DSP_rq)
        print('3: ', vector_HMI_st)
        print('4: ', vector_delay_ac)
```

The output of the above is the following, they are the first 4 prints and it is fine, because it is what they want, but I have **to simplify the code**, so that any type of xml file of the type [example.xml](https://github.com/MR/blob/master/example.xml), can be read not only example1.xml:

[image]

The simplified code is required to bring the data as it is in the names_list variable, but not to use this variable, which is actually hard-coded:

```
        names_list = [
            'Status', 'SetDSP', 'HMI', 'Delay', 'AutoConfigO_Rear',
            'AutoConfigO_Front', 'AutoConfigO_Drvr','AutoConfigO_Allst',
            'RUResReqstStat', 'RUReqstrSystem', 'RUSource', 'DSP' 
            ]
```

So when the client wants to put another XML file with the same structure, but with other names that are not in the code, it can read them without problem. Beforehand thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it, I used a for loop and iterated the dataframe itself:

```
    for i in signals_df.Name:
       signal = signals_df [signals_df.Name.isin ([i])]
       row_values = signal.T
       vector = row_values.iloc [[1]]
       print (vector)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding the questions correctly. my understanding is that

1. you want to dynamically produce the `extract_name_value()` function, and make it not as bulky in your code.
2. Im sorry, but I failed to comprehend the `for i in signal_name: print(i)` part of the question. perhaps you can rephrase the question, and help me understand?

my solution to the `extract_name_value()` part would be using the `exec()` function.
it is a built-in solution for dynamic execution.

```
name_list = ['Status', 'SetDSP', 'HMI', 'Delay', 'AutoConfigO_Rear',
            'AutoConfigO_Front', 'AutoConfigO_Drvr', 'AutoConfigO_Allst',
            'RUResReqstStat', 'RUReqstrSystem', 'RUSource', 'DSP']

def _build_extract_name_value_func(name_list):
  extract_name_value_func = ""
  for name in name_list:
    holder_func = f"""
        signal_{name} = signals_df[signals_df.Name.isin([{name}])]
        row_values_{name} = signal_{name}.T
        vector_{name} = row_values_{name}.iloc[[1]]
        vector_list.append(vector_{name})
        """
    extract_name_value_func += holder_func
  return extract_name_value_func

def extract_name_value(name_list):
  extract_name_value_func = build_extract_name_value_func(name_list)
  exec(extract_name_value_func)
```

the code was not tested with actual data, because I am not familiar with handling xml structures. But I hope the python part can be some help to you.

Comment: Hello and thanks @betrification, to rephrase my question I deleted some lines that I had previously commented and arranged some things, I hope to express myself better... really what the prints of the extract_name_value (signals_df) function are bringing me is correct, I just have to simplify the code because it is repeating a lot and not to use the signals_df.Name of Pandas with (["Xxxxx"]) in hard code, for also later in the code not to use the variable name_list that is also in hard code.